# GLSL Vertex Shader compiles with no display

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to implement phong shading to no avail. I am building the shaders bit by bit (which could be an issue in itself) but here is where I am at currently. I would expect this to output my result (the Utah teapot) as a white image on my black background. It does this correctly when I remove line 18 from the vertex shader, but when the line is there there is no output, and no error. Any ideas?

Fragment Shader:

```
  1 #version 120                                                                                      
  2                                                                                                   
  3 varying vec3 vertexNormal;                                                                        
  4 varying vec3 cameraSpacePos;                                                                      
  5                                                                                                   
  6 vec3 calcSpecular(vec3 l, vec3 n, vec3 v, vec3 cL, vec3 cS, float p)                              
  7 {                                                                                                 
  8     vec3 r =  2.0 * n * (n * l) - l;                                                              
  9     return cL * cS * pow(max(0.0, dot(r, v)), p);                                                 
 10 }                                                                                                 
 11                                                                                                   
 12 vec3 calcDiffuse(vec3 l, vec3 n, vec3 cL, vec3 cD)                                                
 13 {                                                                                                 
 14     return cL * cD * max(0.0, dot(n, l));                                                         
 15 }                                                                                                 
 16                                                                                                   
 17 void main(void)                                                                                   
 18 {                                                                                                 
 19     vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(-1.0, 0.0, -1.0));                                       
 20     vec3 objectColor    = vec3(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);                                                    
 21     vec3 ambientColor   = vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);                                                    
 22     vec3 lightColor     = vec3(0.3, 0.0, 0.3);                                                    
 23     vec3 specularColor  = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);                                                    
 24                                                                                                   
 25     gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);                                                      
 26 }
```

Vertex Shader:

```
  1 #version 120
  2 
  3 uniform mat4 modelView;
  4 uniform mat4 normalModelView;
  5 uniform mat4 projection;
  6 
  7 attribute vec3 position;
  8 attribute vec3 normal;
  9 
 10 varying vec3 vertexNormal;
 11 varying vec3 cameraSpacePos;
 12 
 13 void main(void)
 14 {
 15     vec4 tmpCameraSpacePos = modelView * vec4(position, 1.0);
 16     gl_Position    = projection * tmpCameraSpacePos;
 17 
 18     vertexNormal = (normalModelView * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
 19     cameraSpacePos  = (tmpCameraSpacePos).xyz;
 20 
 21 }
 22
```

It may also be worth mentioning that normal and normalModelView are not currently being set. I had tried with them enabled previously to similar results. My understanding is that they should be set to default values.

Comment: Should you be setting w to 0.0 or 1.0 on line 18?

Comment: @user1118321 A normal is a vector, so translations do not apply to it, and it should have a value of 0.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `.frag' and `.vert' files in a solution file will always `compile` even with syntax errors etc. VS assumes they are correct, whether they display anything or not is down to if they are actually correct or not. Looks like you've sorted the problem though :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that `normal` and `normalModelView` are not being set, my guess is that they are not being set to default values either, and are technically invalid data.  When invalid data is used in a shader, the results are undefined, part of the reason why shaders are difficult to debug.  Make sure that you're providing values for those variables before you try to reference them in the code.

Comment: Yep that was the problem. I thought I had previously read that the behavior was defined (at least for matrices) but that did turn out to be the problem.

Comment: you just gave me the idea that helped me make a breakthrough in debugging a different problem with GLSL that was giving me a black screen with no errors, thanks :)

Btw. the idea was: to just output white for all processed fragments, and work my way backwards from there to see what breaks